# what is the similar ways in Java ArrayList of vector<int> v(100)

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to make ArrayList size 100 when I initialize.
How can I do that?

In C++, vector v(100);

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate an ArrayList, you can specify the initial capacity, but that doesn't populate the ArrayList.

You can use some short cuts with arrays.

For example, you can create an ArrayList of 100 null references with :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(new Integer[100]));
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the constructor [ArrayList(int initialCapacity)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)), which sets the initial size of the backing array to `initialSize`.

Note that this does not actually give you `initialSize` values in the ArrayList, it just sets the size of the backing array. If you need to set some initial values, you need to do something like

`new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(100, 0));`

Answer (score 0):

Constructor defined in [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) can be used and initial capacity can be set to 100. It also avoids resizing of list until threshold is reached.

```
List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]);
```